# Asp ajax, setting custom validator error message

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod, customvalidator

I have a custom validator

`<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ValidateEmptyText="True" ClientValidationFunction="validateStuNum" ControlToValidate="StudentNumTextbox" ID="studentnumValidator" OnServerValidate="ValidateStudentNum" ForeColor="#790000" Display="Dynamic" />`

And I'm making an ajax call to a WebMethod

```
function validateStuNum(src, args) {
                var numTextbox = document.getElementById('<%=StudentNumTextbox.ClientID%>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/ValidateAjaxStudentNum",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'stuNum': numTextbox.value, 'sender':src }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (valid) {
                        if (!valid.d) {
                            document.getElementById('<%=studentNum.ClientID%>').style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFE0";
                        }
                        args.IsValid = valid.d;
                    }
                });
            }

       [WebMethod]
    public static bool ValidateAjaxStudentNum(string stuNum, object sender)
    {
        CustomValidator valid = (CustomValidator) sender;

        const string strRegex = @"\d{9}";
        Regex regex = new Regex(strRegex);
        if (stuNum.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            valid.Text = "This field is required";
            throw new Exception();
        }
        if (!regex.IsMatch(stuNum))
        {
            valid.Text = "Invalid Student number format";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

My problem is that I'm trying to set the validators text property from inside the WebMethod, however I'm sure how to go about doing that. From what I posted, I tried sending `src` to the method and casting it to a CustomValidator with no luck. I just want to be able to have error messages based on what is wrong with the input. Any help is appreciated

Comment: what about totally forget about the asp.net validator and try to show user your own message directly it would be much simpler approach or you can use jquery plugin for form validation it is more customizable and give you more options

Comment: I'll mess around with the jquery plugin for a bit, seems like a good option for what I'm doing.

Comment: Rather than trying to set the `valid` text through your WebMethod, use the webmethod to return the error text, if any, to your ajax call and use jQuery to set the valid.Text to whatever you need. Much easier than mucking around with custom validators and you code will remain cleaner